# Area of hyperbolic triangle

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebra-precalculus

Hello friend i am working on hyperbolic triangle specialy the angle-side-angle situation, witch mean that if we are given two angle $\alpha,\beta$ and the lenght c, so if we have $$\alpha +\beta <\pi \qquad and \qquad \cosh(c)<\dfrac{1+cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta)}{\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)}.$$
Then there exist unique triangle T with  :
\begin{equation}
\tanh a = \dfrac{2\sin \alpha }{\sin(\alpha +\beta)\coth(\dfrac{c}{2})+\sin (\alpha -\beta)\tanh(\dfrac{c}{2})}.
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\tanh b = \dfrac{2\sin \beta }{\sin(\alpha +\beta)\coth(\dfrac{c}{2})-\sin (\alpha -\beta)\tanh(\dfrac{c}{2})}.
\end{equation}
And we know that :
\begin{equation}
\sin( A/2) = \dfrac{\sinh (a) \sinh (c) \sin(\beta) }{4\cosh(a/2)\cosh(b/2)\cosh(c/2)},
\end{equation}
where A is the area of triangle.
what i am searching is that to prove that for triangle that $c<\pi/3$ we have :
**\begin{equation}
\frac{A}{2}<\alpha +\beta.
\end{equation}**
NB: i already check it numercaly but i need a proof. 
Thank you

Comment: You can visit this for more details, I think this will be very helpful for you. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VhFYqHzVM-M

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun first thank you for comment. I saw that video but it seems that is not what i am looking for